# How to convert .xls file to .htm file using JXL api?

Tags: java, excel, jxl

I have a Microsoft Excel file and I need to convert it to HTML. In excel, it is pretty simple to do: there is the "Save As..." option and you select "web page (.htm)". But I need to do this from Java, using JXL. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Read the rows and columns and write them out as an HTYML <TABLE> using <TR> and <TD> tags.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at either the `XML` or `CSV` classes: they are examples of how to extract data from an Excel document and do something interesting with it.

You may also want to take a look at the [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) project if JXL doesn't look like it's going to meet your needs.